# Rendering 2 ListBoxes, one containing strings, one containing the lengths of the same strings

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] names = new string [20]                  

  {"John","Susy","Obedia","Saul","Abram","Lincoln","Abraham","Eli","Kain","Abel",                                    


   "Will","Smitty","Scott","Julie","Ramona","Melissa","Todd","Lilly","Naomi","Leland"};

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Question #1 Pop Names in listbox
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(names[i]);
        }
    }
```

This is how I populated my `listbox1` but now in `listbox2` I want to show the length of each name. I'm wondering how I would find this in C# code?

Comment: Is this homework?  If it is you should tag it as such

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `names[i].Length`??

Comment: You don't need to indicate a size if you are going to fill the array with data when you declare it.

Comment: I choose to right now. I don't need to do a lot of this but I am. This is a review for a final. Its not graded just for my own review for final

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Question #1 Pop Names in listbox
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(names[i]);
        listBox2.Items.Add(names[i].Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: .Length perfect that is what I needed but I also put this in a try catch block if anyone else needs to see this for help Thx for your answer

Comment: Also, it is best to do some initial research (simple googling in this case) to try and find an answer on your own, before posting to SO. Especially in the case of homework :)

Comment: not homework its a review for a final. My teacher recommended this site. ps this doesn't get graded I don't cheat thx.

Comment: No problem, I was not accusing you of cheating. Just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. Its just others have and I don't understand why they presume things. Im new to this and heard it was a good cite but from my using of it doesn't quite seem that way

Comment: I always get respect taken off lately. So how do i gain it. Do I write Questions I can't figure out or stuff I know to help others??

Comment: The answer is both. Your reputation will grow as long as you keep asking questions and providing help to posters who need answers, all the while following the rules of stack overflow. There will be times when your answer is not picked, or people criticize your question. Just remember to not take it personally. This format is what makes this site great!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I won't give away the full answer.

You want to use the [`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) property in C# to get the length of each name.

```
string str = "Michael";
int len = str.Length;
```

Now, you can choose whether to compile the properties from the `listBox1` itself, or by taking your original array and iterating through that.

Comment: my homework doesn't get turned in. Its a review for a final. I don't cheat so pls don't assume

Comment: @ScottKennedy I'm not assuming you cheat. I just don't want to give you the answer. What would you learn from that?

Comment: Ok good thx and I appreciate that a lot. I was just missing the .Length lol so you did give me the answer. :)